How to sort Pandas dataframe by column using the key argument
Assume a Pandas data frame (for the sake of simplicity, let's say with three columns). The columns are titled A, B and d.
$ import pandas as pd
$ df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, "a"], [1, "b", 3], ["c", 4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B', 'd'])
$ df
   A  B  d
0  1  2  a
1  1  b  3
2  c  4  6

Further assume that I wish to sort the data frame so that the columns have exactly the following order: d, A, B. The rows of the data frame shall not be rearranged in any way. The desired output is:
$ col_target_order = ['d', 'A', 'B']
$ df_desired
   d  A  B
0  a  1  2
1  3  1  b
2  6  c  4

I know that this can be done via the sort_index function of pandas. However, the following won't work, as the input list (col_target_order) is not callable:
$ df.sort_index(axis=1, key=col_target_order)

What key specification do I have to use?

Don't sort, just index:
out = df[col_target_order]

For the sake of the argument, you could sort_index with a crafted Series as key:
df.sort_index(axis=1, key=pd.Series(range(len(col_target_order)), index=col_target_order).get)

Or an Index indexer:
df.sort_index(axis=1, key=pd.Index(col_target_order).get_indexer)

Output:
   d  A  B
0  a  1  2
1  3  1  b
2  6  c  4


Nothing too extra here needed, you can pass those columns directly into the square bracket indexing, the second portion of a .loc or a reindex(…, axis=1)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, "a"], [1, "b", 3], ["c", 4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B', 'd'])
col_target_order = ['d', 'A', 'B']

print(
    df[['d', 'A', 'B']],
    df[col_target_order],
    df.reindex(columns=col_target_order),
    sep='\n\n'
)

## all outputs:
#    d  A  B
# 0  a  1  2
# 1  3  1  b
# 2  6  c  4

Note that if col_target_order has a column that does not exist, the first two approaches will fail with a KeyError. The .reindex approach will insert the column and populate its rows with NaNs.
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, "a"], [1, "b", 3], ["c", 4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B', 'd'])
col_target_order = ['d', 'A', 'B', 'Z']

try:
    print(df[col_target_order]) # KeyError
except KeyError:
    print('`col_target_order` column not found!')

print(df.reindex(columns=col_target_order))
#    d  A  B   Z
# 0  a  1  2 NaN
# 1  3  1  b NaN
# 2  6  c  4 NaN

If you want to drop any columns that appear in col_target_order but do not
exist in the DataFrame you can find the intersection with the columns.
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, "a"], [1, "b", 3], ["c", 4, 6]], columns=['A', 'B', 'd'])
col_target_order = ['d', 'A', 'B', 'Z']

overlapping_cols = df.columns.intersection(col_target_order)
print(df[overlapping_cols]) # 'Z' was dropped!
#    A  B  d
# 0  1  2  a
# 1  1  b  3
# 2  c  4  6

